# Google App Engine Backend URL on dev server. How to find out in code?

Tags: google-app-engine

The question is about Google App Engine Backend.
How do I find out the backend url on dev server in code ? We have simple url formating rule on production server http://backendName.appName.appspot.com 
But url is random on development server, it's related to some random port http://localhost:xxxx

So how do I find out this dev url *in code* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can programmatically [access backends](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview.html#Addressing_Backends) via [Backends API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/backends/package-summary.html). This also works on dev server.

Comment: These API will help us spot the backend which is serving the request, however I was looking for the URL (especially the port) in which local backend server is running. This will help me identifying the backend URL I need to invoke during automatic integration test. It production its not a problem as its predictable.